# Programming error with SQlite3

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

i am getting the below errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PYTHON SUPER INP\DB test - Copy1220.py", line 29, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__":main()
  File "D:\PYTHON SUPER INP\DB test - Copy1220.py", line 17, in main
    addCust("Zach")
  File "D:\PYTHON SUPER INP\DB test - Copy1220.py", line 13, in addCust
    VALUES(?)""",(name))
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current 
     statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
```

with my follwing code

```
import sqlite3

createDb = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
queryCurs = createDb.cursor()

def createTable():
    queryCurs.execute(''' CREATE TABLE customers
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)''')

def addCust(name):
    queryCurs.execute("""INSERT INTO customers (name)
    VALUES(?)""",(name))

def main():
    createTable()
    addCust("Zach")
    createDb.commit()

    queryCurs.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")

    for i in queryCurs:
      print "/n"
      for j in i:
          print j

queryCurs.close

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
def addCust(name):
    queryCurs.execute("""INSERT INTO customers (name)
    VALUES(?)""",(name))
```

When you do `(name)` it's the same as `name` - so if `name` is `"Zach"` then it's a string, that's iterable and has a length of 4, instead, make it a one tuple or a list, eg:

```
(name,) # notice the trailing comma
```

eg:

```
>>> len(('Zach')) # same as len('Zach')
4
>>> len(('Zach',)) # now a one-tuple containing a string of length 4
1
```

**Couple of other notes - see code comments**:

```
    for i in queryCurs:
      print "/n" # <-- to print a new line - use `\n` - not `/n`
      for j in i:
          print j

queryCurs.close # this should be queryCurs.close() (eg - call the method)
```